# Confused about the ways to write code for instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am quite confused on how we write instance variables in Rails.

```
 Posted by: <%= link_to(@item.user.username, store_path(@item.user)) %>
 Price: <%= number_to_currency @item.price %>
```

vs

```
Subject: <%= subject_name @item %>
```

I am just curious what is the difference between (i) subject_name @item and (ii) @item.price?

Is it not supposed to be @item.subject_name?

Comment: `subject_name` will be defined in your helper mostly..

Comment: `subject_name` is probably [helper method](http://codefol.io/posts/Where-Do-I-Put-My-Code) which is just like any other method available to be called in `view`. In `@item.price`, `@item` is instance object of class `Item` and `price` is the attribute of that model. That's why it is callable with `dot` notation

Comment: You can call **@item.subject_name** only if **subject_name** is a instance method inside `Item` Model or it's a field inside `items` table. Here, it's probably a helper method.

Comment: number_to_currency should be method which accepting numbers @item is your instance object and price may be method inside item model or property of item model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect that `subject_name` isn't a variable, but a method. I guess you have a method `subject_name` defined in one of your helper files that takes an argument - `@item` in this example.